# Where Can I Find the Video Player In The Edit Media Screen

Tags: editor

I want to use the video player that you see in this screenshot as a player on my webpage.

Where can I find the code for this player?

Is there a function that I can hook into to display my video in this player?

[image: WordPress Edit Media Screen]

Thank You

Comment: [Try this link](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/04/08/audio-video-support-in-core/). It show how you can use video and audio.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that but I was specifically looking for that exact player with the skin and all.